# ImportError: matplotlib requires pyparsing >= 1.5.6

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyparsing

I am trying to import `matplotlib` but getting the following error:

```
>>> import matplotlib

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 121, in <module>
    '.'.join(str(x) for x in _required)))
ImportError: matplotlib requires pyparsing >= 1.5.6
```

It looks like I have installed the `pyparsing` package successfully:

```
>>> import pyparsing
>>> print pyparsing.__version__
1.5.6
```

Comment: I have seen cases where the import error message was misleading; seeing the whole trace back would be useful

Comment: @behzad.nouri You're right. I have added the full output.

Comment: Try updating pyparsing -- I think the latest version is actually 2.0.1. I'm not certain if that'll solve the issue, though.

Comment: @Michael0x2a Hi and thanks for your comment. Yes, that's actually what I've done in the first place but unfortunately got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

For me, this was the only combination of versions getting it to work...

```
pyparsing = 1.5.6
reportlab =  2.7
matplotlib = 1.2.1
```

on ubuntu 12.04 and python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

This combination seems to work for me

```
matplotlib (1.5.0)
pyparsing (2.0.6)
reportlab (2.5)
```